# Ruby: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass / inheritance problem?

Tags: ruby

could you please explain to me why I get this error, I guess it's due to the way I defined my instance variable:

I have a parent class named 'character'

```
class Character
  attr_accessor :coordinates

  def initialize (coordinates)
    @coordinates = []
  end
end
```

And a child class:

```
require_relative 'characters'

class Hero < Character
  attr_accessor :lives, :coordinates

  def initialize (lives, coordinates)
    @lives = lives
    @coordinates = []
  end

  def get_direction
    puts "Press up/down and left/right keys to start moving your hero"
    next_move = gets.chomp.downcase
    if next_move == 'left'
      @coordinates = [0, -1]
    elsif next_move == 'right'
      @coordinates = [0, 1]
    elsif next_move == 'up'
      @coordinates = [-1, 0]
      elif next_move == 'down'
      @coordinates = [1, 0]
    end
  end
end
```

Then I have a main.rb where I want to use the @coordinates of my character and check whether he's still on the map. Here is the method in the main.rb:

```
def check_hero_position
    print @coordinates.class
    print @coordinates[0].class

    # @hero_location[1] += @coordinates[1]
    # case  
    # when (@hero_location[0] < 1) || (@hero_location[0] > @map_size[0]) 
    #   puts "error-x"
    # when
    #   (@hero_location[1] < 0) || (@hero_location[1] > @map_size[1])
    #   puts "error-y"
    # end
end
```

When I run the code, I get this error for the line in the method where I try to print the class of coordinates[0].
`check_hero_position': undefined method`[]' for nil:NilClass

Did I use properly the `coordinates` instance variable?
Second, how can I compare the values of two arrays? I commented the code in the method since is not correct.

Comment: You are using `@coordinates` outside the `class`, to access it you need to instantiate a `Hero` object, then call the `coordinates` method on it.

Comment: @iGian indicated you the right way. Then remember the syntax is `my_hero_variable.coordinates` ... not `coordinates.class`

Answer (score 1):

First thing you are assigning empty array to `@coordinates` in initialize, so change as below:

```
class Hero < Character
  attr_accessor :lives, :coordinates

  def initialize (lives, coordinates = [])
    @lives = lives
    @coordinates = coordinates # assign the value of the parameter
  end

  def get_direction
    puts "Press up/down and left/right keys to start moving your hero"
    next_move = gets.chomp.downcase
    if next_move == 'left'
      @coordinates = [0, -1]
    elsif next_move == 'right'
      @coordinates = [0, 1]
    elsif next_move == 'up'
      @coordinates = [-1, 0]
      elif next_move == 'down'
      @coordinates = [1, 0]
    end
  end
end
```

Then you need to instantiate the Hero object, passing parameters to initialise:

```
hero = Hero.new('something', [:x,:y,:z])
```

And now you can call the method on it:

```
p hero.coordinates #=> [:x, :y, :z]
```

---

For the second part of the question, I can suggest you to take a look at [Vector](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html) class for moving and comparing, maybe you can find useful:

```
require 'matrix'

position = Vector[1, 2]
move = Vector[4, 6]

new_position = position + move #=> Vector[5, 8]
p new_position.magnitude #=> 9.433981132056603 (distance from origin 0, 0)
```